# Changing background color for items of Spinner

Tags: android

I am working on Android application.I am using Spinner control and added items to it.
Is there a way to change the  background color of items  in spinner.

 can any one help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you completely want to customize your background spinner, you should use 9patch background.

Here is a tutorial that explain how to do that :
http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57

Otherwise, the solution given by user432209 is the simplest. 
However, if you want to do that in xml layout :

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
         ...
         android:background="#YOUR_HEXA_COLOR"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(int color)
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a different background color for each spinner choice in xml? I have 30+ choices in my spinner, so I want to alternate the background colors between red and blue.

Comment: problem is, that when I use `mSpinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` then the whole Spinner just turns red - even the black drop down arrow disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `android:popupBackground="YOUR COLOR"` which will define the items background not the whole spinner's background.