# Android Spinner Text Background Colour and Theme

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem that has manifested itself since I tried to add themes to my application. At the moment I am just using themes to change the background colour of the screen. The problem is that as well as the background of the screen changing to the theme colour, the background of the text in the spinner control also changes to that colour. When the drop down is displayed the spinner control is replaced by the block background colour.

The themes are defined as follows:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="android:style/Theme">
</style>

<style name="Theme.Pink">
       <item name="android:background">#ffc0cb</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Yellow">
       <item name="android:background">#FFE97E</item>
</style>
```

Themes are set in the Activity OnCreate with:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme.Yellow);
```

The Spinner is set up with:

```
    bowAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_style, bowCursor, 
                 new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_BOW_NAME }, 
                 new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    bowAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bowSelectSpinner.setAdapter(bowAdapter);
```

spinner_style.xml contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@android:id/text1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/but_txt_size"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

How can I stop the spinner picking up the background colour specified in the theme?

I have been chasung this for 2 days now so any hints gratefully rec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this answer: [Changing background color for items of Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294111/changing-background-color-for-items-of-spinner). No matter what your theme's background is, you can set your spinner background to override it.

You can do, from code:

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(int color)
```

or, from xml

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
     ...
     android:background="#YOUR_HEXA_COLOR"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the problem is though that the colour of the background of the text on the spinner control gets set to that of the screen background. So on the standard grey shaded spinner control I get a rectangle, coloured the same as the background, with the text in it, rather than the text just appearing with a transparent background.

Comment: Then make your background transparent! :) Set it's background to  android:color/transparent.

Comment: Before replying that 'I had already tried that' I thought I had better check my code .. It turns out that I was setting android:colorBackground which had no effect,setting the background color properly has fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.