# Android: how to give alternate colors to the spinner items

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner with the items as below

```
ArrayAdapter<Message> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, messages);
                arrayadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview);
```

i want to give altenate colors to the listitems.how can i do that.Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to create a `CustomDialog` having `ListView` inside which acts like a Spinner.

Comment: @ChintanRathod can u give some examples or links

Comment: You need to create a custom Adapter and override the getView() method instead of ArrayAdapter

Comment: Do you know how to create a ListView with CustomAdapter? and Custom Dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =
    new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myList) {
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position % 2 == 0) { // we're on an even row
           view.setBackgroundColor(evenColor);
        } else {
           view.setBackgroundColor(oddColor);
        }
       return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are links which might be useful to create a custom spinner of your choice.

1) http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html 
2) http://www.edureka.in/blog/custom-spinner-in-android/  
3) [Android Spinner with different layouts for "drop down state" and "closed state"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647299/android-spinner-with-different-layouts-for-drop-down-state-and-closed-state)

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use the following code

```
 @Override
       public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
               Context mContext = this.getContext();
               LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
         } 
    TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTarget);
    tv.setText(testarray.get(position));
    switch (position) {
    case 0:  tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);  
    break; 
    case 1:  tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    break;
    default:  tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    break;
    }
return v;  
              }              
       };     
       pSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter); 
}
```

Comment: Have a look of this link too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294111/changing-background-color-for-items-of-spinner