# How to change background color of spinner items

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner) library for spinner. I want to change the color of already selected items from the list in the spinner. How can I do it? This is how I'm populating the data onclick of the spinner:

```
spinner1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Cursor crs = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ ItemsTable.TABLE_ZONE +" WHERE "+ ItemsTable.COLUMN_ZONE_ID +"<>"+ zone_id1
                            +" AND "+ ItemsTable.COLUMN_ZONE_ID +"<>"+ zone_id2 +" AND "+ ItemsTable.COLUMN_ZONE_ID +"<>"+ zone_id3 +"", null);
                    Integer[crs.getCount()];
                    List<Zone> listOfZones = new ArrayList<Zone>();

                    while(crs.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String title = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("title"));
                        Integer title_id = crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex("id"));

                        listOfZones.add(new Zone(title_id, title));

                    }
                    crs.close();

                    ArrayAdapter<Zone> zoneadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Zone>(getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, listOfZones);
                    spinner1.setAdapter(zoneadapter);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

In the code above I'm removing the items from the list which are already selected but I want to change the background color of the items already selected.

Comment: Crate custom Layout for that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407626/custom-layout-for-spinner-itema)

Comment: Follow this tutorial : https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-spinner-item-background-color.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing background color for items of Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294111/changing-background-color-for-items-of-spinner)

Comment: @ADM, The question you posted is asking how to change the background color of every item in the list. That's pretty easy to do. I wouldn't have posted a question if I had the same issue. My problem is I want to change the background of already selected items that can't be done just using xml.

Comment: @3iL if you want to change pre-selected item then i think you need to use Custom adapter . Just override the `ArrayAdapter` and validate in `getView()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give background color by creating `xml` file for `spinner layout`. Follow below steps.

1) You need to create one `xml` file under `layout` folder.

2) Create layout which includes one `TextView` which show item names.

3) Give background color to main `rootview` layout. For example `android:background="@color/anycolor"`.

And bind this layout in spinner adapter.

Here is custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<Zone> listOfZones;
LayoutInflater inflter;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext,  List<Zone> listOfZones) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.listOfZones = listOfZones;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return flags.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name, null);
    TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    names.setText(listOfZones.get(i).yourObjectName);
    return view;
}}
```

And bind this to spinner like this:

```
 CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listOfZones);
 your_spinner.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```